# Screen Wrapping using GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, game-physics, glfw, glm-math

I'm attempting to make an asteroids clone, but am having issues with screen wrapping for when my game objects go off of the screen.

My current approach is to compare the bounds of the screen against the position of the object, which is a `glm::vec4`, like so:

```cpp
void checkPosition(glm::vec4& position)
{
    int width, height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(WindowManager::getInstance().getWindow(), &width, &height);

    if (position.x < -100.0f)
    {
        position.x = width;
    }

    if (position.x > (float)width + 100.0f)
    {
        position.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (position.y < -100.0f)
    {
        position.y = height;
    }

    if (position.y > (float)height + 100.0f)
    {
        position.y = 0.0f;
    }
}
```

I added a bit of a buffer to the bounds-checking so the object doesn't get caught in a loop being swapped from edge to edge (hence the reasons for the `(float)width + 100.0f` part).

The issue: Once my object gets teleported, the translation for it seems to get completely thrown off.  For example, when my player ship goes off screen and gets repositioned to the opposite x and y coordinates, the x-coordinate stops changing completely.  After that, if I move the ship to be off screen in the y direction, the y-coordinate also stops responding to changes.

What am I missing?  I'm open to other approaches to get this effect working.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I think I've found the issue.  Just setting `position` completely messes up my projection matrix.  The workaround is to call some function (in my case `translate`) that sets the identity matrix when you update positions.  This is what that looks like for me:

```cpp
void Transform::translate(glm::vec3 vector)
{
    glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f); // identity matrix
    trans = glm::translate(trans, vector);
    position = trans * position;
}
```